# Managing layout runtime android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting runtime dynamic imagebutton displayed but i am having some things that are displayed on the screen before, so now when i add my runtime imagebutton it will overlap the previous static display and i want to add the runtime imagebutton after the static layout which comes through xml. please help.

```
        for (int i =0;i<adapt_objmenu.image_array.length;i++){
         ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton(myrefmenu);
            b1.setId(100 + i);
            b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet_1);
         //   b1.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)
          b1.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);

          b1.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bg_navitionbar);




           // b1.setText(adapt_objmenu.city_name_array[i]);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (i > 0) {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, b1.getId() - 1);
            }   
            b1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            relative.addView(b1);

    //relate.addView(b1, i,  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));

    //height = height+80;



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the ImageButton to your Layout?

If you use LinearLayout as the main Layout then that wouldn't happen...

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myWrapperLayout);
 ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton(R.id.imgBtn); 
        imgBtn.setText("MyImageButton"); 
        layout.addView(imgBtn);
```

Comment: What is the orientation of your LinearLayout?

Comment: add some padding using yourView.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom); so that your view is not on top of other view

Comment: RelativeLayout allows a view to be on top of other views, if you are ok with using LinearLayout, use it, because it guarantees that a view will not be over another view...

Comment: ok then i'll use linear layout now but how to put it below the other static view, please help